# Parse Exception Error Message

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com as my backend.  I am attempting to update the user's call sign, but Parse keeps throwing an exception.  When trying to read what the message is, I get a exception error message "null pointer."

**ERROR MESSAGE**

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.parse.ParseException.getMessage()' on a null object reference
            at Logic.BusinessLogic$8.done(BusinessLogic.java:303)
            at Logic.BusinessLogic$8.done(BusinessLogic.java:293)
            at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$1.done(ParseTaskUtils.java:66)
            at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$1.done(ParseTaskUtils.java:63)
            at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:107)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

**CODE**

```
public static void UpdateCallSign(String newCallSign, final Context cntx) {

    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    user.put("CallSign", newCallSign);
    user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {

                Toast.makeText(cntx, "Call Sign Updated",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  Log.d("Success", "Success");
                // Saved successfully
            } else {
                // ParseException

                    Log.d("Exception: ", e.getMessage());

            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you got your `if` statement backwards. Based on your comments in the code, I think you wanted this:

```
public static void UpdateCallSign(String newCallSign, final Context cntx) {

    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    user.put("CallSign", newCallSign);
    user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) { <--------- This is what I changed
                // Saved successfully
                Toast.makeText(cntx, "Call Sign Updated",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("Success", "Success");
            } else {
                // ParseException
                Log.d("Exception: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

}
```

So change the `if (e != null)` to `if (e == null)` and you should be good. The error message was telling you that when you called `e.getMessage()`, `e` was `null`. In your original code, of course this is the case, since the `else` clause is only triggered when `e == null`.

Comment: Thank you!  It is weird, I think I copied this directly off of Parse's blog somewhere.  Oh well!  Thank you so much!